# Issues with node.js bot and sqlite

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite

I created a staty command that shows them stats from sqlite.

When I run the bot and type staty, I get the error "TypeError: rows.forEach is not a function"

Here is my code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const EmbedUtil = require("../../utils/EmbedUtil");
const BaseCommand = require("../BaseCommand");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../data/config.json");
const MessageUtil = require("../../utils/MessageUtil");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

class StatsCommand extends BaseCommand {
    constructor() {
        super("staty");
    }

    execute(bot, msg, args) {
        if (args.length === 0) {
            const embed = EmbedUtil.createEmbed("Blad", [
                `Poprawne użycie: ${config.prefix}staty (nick)`,
            ]);
            MessageUtil.replyMessageAndDelete(embed, msg, 7);
            return;
        }

        let db = new sqlite3.Database("db/DataBase.db");

        db.get(
            "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE nick = ?", [args[0]],
            (err, rows, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    msg.reply("Podany gracz nie istnieje!");
                    return;
                }

                rows.forEach((nick, kills, points, deaths) => {
                    const embed = EmbedUtil.createEmbed(
                        "**STATYSTYKI**",
                        `**Gracz:** ${player} \n**Zabojstwa:** ${kills} \n**Smierci:** ${deaths} \n**Punkty:** ${points} \n**Gildia:** ${guild}`
                    );
                    msg.channel.send(embed);
                    return;
                });
            }
        );
    }
}

module.exports = StatsCommand;
```

I don't understand why forEach is no function.

Can someone help me? What may be the problem?

Comment: rtm: https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#getsql--param---callback its not an array